# Question about commutator

Tags: group-theory

Let $A$ be an abelian normal subgroup of $G$ and $x\in G$. How can we prove the following?

> (a) The mapping  $A\mapsto A$ given by $a \mapsto [a,x]$ is a homomorphism.
>
> (b) $[A,\langle x\rangle]=\{[a,x]|a\in A\}$.

Comment: We probably need $A$ abelian.

Comment: My bad, it's my first time to use this.

Comment: No problem. ${}{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint*: $$[ab,x]=[a,x]^b[b,x]$$

> *Stronger Hint*: 
>  $[a,x^2]\in A$ because $A$ is normal.  What can you say about $[a,x^2]$ when $a\in \text{Ker}(a\mapsto [a,x])$?

Comment: Of course, we're mapping $A\to A$, so we should be calculating $[ab,x]$.

Comment: I could prove the (a) ,whether we use the same method to prove (b)

Comment: @user53587 Use (a) to prove (b). Hint: What are the relevant groups of a homomorphism? E.g. the kernel is one.